# Почему не отображаются элементы TreeView JavaFX при компиляции?

Tags: java, javafx, treeview

Компилирую код:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

public class Controller {
    @FXML
    public TreeView<String> serverTreeView;

    public void initialize (){
        TreeItem<String> rootNoode = new TreeItem<String>("root");
        rootNoode.setExpanded(true);
        rootNoode.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<String>("34234"));
        serverTreeView = new TreeView<>(rootNoode);
        serverTreeView.setRoot(rootNoode);
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <TreeView fx:id="serverTreeView" layoutX="180.0" layoutY="55.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

не вижу элементов списка при компиляции.  в чем проблема?

[image: То что компилируется]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка у тебя в этом месте

```
public void initialize (){
    TreeItem<String> rootNoode = new TreeItem<String>("root");
    rootNoode.setExpanded(true);
    rootNoode.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<String>("34234"));
    serverTreeView = new TreeView<>(rootNoode); // вот тут
    serverTreeView.setRoot(rootNoode);
}
```

Тебе не надо самому создавать `TreeView`, оно у тебя создается, когда у тебя зачитывается fxml. Чтобы исправить, сделай так

```
public void initialize (){
    TreeItem<String> rootNoode = new TreeItem<String>("root");
    rootNoode.setExpanded(true);
    rootNoode.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<String>("34234"));
    serverTreeView.setRoot(rootNoode);
}
```